# How to see the assembly for methods using jitclass

Tags: python, numba

I have this simple MWE:

```py
from numba.experimental import jitclass
import numba
    
@jitclass([('value', numba.int32), ('array', numba.float32[:])])
class Bag:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.array = np.zeros(value, dtype=np.float32)
    
    def increment(self, val):
        for i in range(self.size):
          self.array[i] += val
        return self.array
    
bag = Bag(10)
```

How can I see the assembly for the class and for the increment method?  I can't see how to use `inspect_asm()` for this.